# Discourse API via AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, nginx, ionic-framework, discourse

I am looking to interact with an instance of the Discourse forum software via AJAX.

I have not installed the Discourse API gem, rather I would like to send AJAX requests to the pre-existing Discourse web instance. Do I need the API gem to do this?

I can perform GET requests just fine, but for some reason performing a POST to "/posts" fails. I am adding the API key and api_username in the query string. I have enabled all of the CORS settings in the admin options as well as my app.yml file. I have also set the nginx headers to allow CORS.

It is failing at OPTIONS every time. Really not sure what I'm missing. Any help would be hugely appreciated.